# Sencha Touch cross-domain jsonp returns a syntax error

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch, cross-domain

I have the following code to retrieve the a JSON structure from another domain and display it on the page.

However, nothing appears and I get the this error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : People.json:2

I've passed my JSON into a JSON validator and it came back as valid.

**Here is my code:**

```
    Ext.define("Person", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        config: {
            fields: [
                { name: 'Id', type: 'int'},
                { name: 'Name', type: 'string'},
                { name: 'Email', type: 'string'}
            ]
        }
    });

    var myStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
        model: "Person",
        proxy: {
            type: "jsonp",
            url: 'http://example.com/People.json',
            reader: {
                type: "json",
                rootProperty: "Person"
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });

    Ext.create("Ext.List", {
        fullscreen: true,
        store: myStore,
        itemTpl: "{Name}, {Id}"
    });
```

**Here are the contents of my JSON file:**

```
{
    "Person": [
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Name": "Robert Lara",
            "Email": "rolara@example.com"
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Tom Hicks",
            "Email": "tohicks@example.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONP is not literally transporting JSON, it expects `http://example.com/People.json` to be Javascript file calling a callback function.

You have taken care of the client side part of JSONP using Sencha, but you have to prepare server side to work with it.

The [Sencha docs on JSONP](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP) have a paragraph and some code examples under the title **Implementing on the server side**:

Also [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) explains what JSONP is all about.

Comment: According the the Sencha documentation, this is taken care of for you: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP - am I missing something in my code?

Comment: Sencha take care of client side part of JSONP, you have to prepare server side to work with it. Check out paragraph **Implementing on the server side** in doc from your link